# How to pass video node from resolve/database to node definitions in graphql relay?

Tags: javascript, graphql, relayjs, graphql-js

My node definitions looks like this:

```
class Store {}
let store = new Store()

let nodeDefs = nodeDefinitions(
  (globalId) => {
    let type = fromGlobalId(globalId).type
    let id = fromGlobalId(globalId).id
    if (type === 'Store') {
      return store
    }
    if (type === 'Video') {
      return docClient.query(
        Object.assign(
          {},
          {TableName: videosTable},
          {KeyConditionExpression: 'id = :id'},
          {ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':id': id }}
        )
      ).promise().then(dataToConnection)
    }
    return null
  },
  (obj) => {
    if (obj instanceof Store) {
      return storeType
    }
    if (obj instanceof Video) {
      return videoType
    }
    return null
  }
)
```

The problem is that video node is always null, even when actual video is being returned from the database, because for it to not be null I need to look it up based on id or somehow fetch it from database.

This is the video node I am referring to:

```
video: {
  type: videoType,
  args: Object.assign(
    {},
    connectionArgs,
    {id: {type: GraphQLString}}
  ),
  resolve: (_, args) => {

    return docClient.query(
      Object.assign(
        {},
        {TableName: pokemonTable},
        {KeyConditionExpression: 'id = :id'},
        {ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':id': args.id }},
        paginationToParams(args)
      )
    ).promise().then(dataToConnection)

  }

},
```

and

```
const videoType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Video',
  fields: () => ({
    id: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID),
      resolve: (obj) => obj.id
    },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    url: { type: GraphQLString }
  }),
  interfaces: [nodeDefs.nodeInterface]
})

const allVideosConnection = connectionDefinitions({
  name: 'Video',
  nodeType: videoType
})
```

I tried doing database query directly inside node definitions, but that didn't work.

`dataToConnection` just converts the output of dynamoDB:

```
video DATA!!  { Items: 
   [ { id: 'f4623d92-3b48-4e1a-bfcc-01ff3c8cf754',
       url: 'http://www.pokkentournament.com/assets/img/characters/char-detail/detail-pikachuLibre.png',
       name: 'YAHOO' } ],
  Count: 1,
  ScannedCount: 1 }
```

into something that graphql relay understands:

```
video dataToConnection!!  { edges: 
   [ { cursor: 'ZHluYW1vZGJjb25uZWN0aW9uOmY0NjIzZDkyLTNiNDgtNGUxYS1iZmNjLTAxZmYzYzhjZjc1NA==',
       node: [Object] } ],
  pageInfo: 
   { startCursor: 'ZHluYW1vZGJjb25uZWN0aW9uOmY0NjIzZDkyLTNiNDgtNGUxYS1iZmNjLTAxZmYzYzhjZjc1NA==',
     endCursor: 'ZHluYW1vZGJjb25uZWN0aW9uOmY0NjIzZDkyLTNiNDgtNGUxYS1iZmNjLTAxZmYzYzhjZjc1NA==',
     hasPreviousPage: false,
     hasNextPage: false } }
```

and the function itself can be found here: https://github.com/dowjones/graphql-dynamodb-connections/pull/3/files

It could be the problem.

Also, asking/querying for id makes the whole video object null:

[image]

But omitting id from the query returns something, whether querying with relay id:

[image]

or database id

[image]

and querying for all of the videos works:

[image]

The interesting part is that I get exactly same problem even if I delete the video part from node definitions:

```
let nodeDefs = nodeDefinitions(
  (globalId) => {
    let type = fromGlobalId(globalId).type
    let id = fromGlobalId(globalId).id
    if (type === 'Store') {
      return store
    }
    return null
  },
  (obj) => {
    if (obj instanceof Store) {
      return storeType
    }
    return null
  }
)
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

I did some digging and found that interfaces in fact is `undefined`

```
const storeType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Store',
  fields: () => ({
    id: globalIdField('Store'),

    allVideosConnection: {
      type: allVideosConnection.connectionType,
      args: Object.assign(
        {},
        connectionArgs
      ),
      resolve: (_, args) => {

        return docClient.scan(
          Object.assign(
            {},
            {TableName: pokemonTable},
            paginationToParams(args)
          )
        ).promise().then(dataToConnection)
      }
    },

    video: {
      type: videoType,
      args: Object.assign(
        {},
        connectionArgs,
        {id: {type: GraphQLString}}
      ),
      resolve: (_, args) => {

        return docClient.query(
          Object.assign(
            {},
            {TableName: pokemonTable},
            {KeyConditionExpression: 'id = :id'},
            {ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':id': args.id }},
            paginationToParams(args)
          )
        ).promise().then(dataToConnection)

      }

    }

  }),

  interfaces: [nodeDefs.nodeInterface]

})





console.dir(storeType.interfaces, { depth: null })
```

prints `undefined`

Why? I clearly define them at the top!

Also, I can do that:

[image]

But this doesn't work:

[image]

This is what is being returned in `video: {}` resolve:

```
{ edges: 
   [ { cursor: 'ZHluYW1vZGJjb25uZWN0aW9uOmY0NjIzZDkyLTNiNDgtNGUxYS1iZmNjLTAxZmYzYzhjZjc1NA==',
       node: 
        { id: 'f4623d92-3b48-4e1a-bfcc-01ff3c8cf754',
          url: 'http://www.pokkentournament.com/assets/img/characters/char-detail/detail-pikachuLibre.png',
          name: 'YAHOO' } } ],
  pageInfo: 
   { startCursor: 'ZHluYW1vZGJjb25uZWN0aW9uOmY0NjIzZDkyLTNiNDgtNGUxYS1iZmNjLTAxZmYzYzhjZjc1NA==',
     endCursor: 'ZHluYW1vZGJjb25uZWN0aW9uOmY0NjIzZDkyLTNiNDgtNGUxYS1iZmNjLTAxZmYzYzhjZjc1NA==',
     hasPreviousPage: false,
     hasNextPage: false } }
```

Somehow that's okay for `allVideosConnection`, but not okay (ends up `null`) for `video`

Do I need to convert ids of nodes to global IDs? using `toGlobalId` ? Just for `video` ?

Because another thing I noticed is that if I

```
console.log('fromGlobalId', fromGlobalId(globalId))
```

inside my node definitions, this query:

```
{
  node(id: "f4623d92-3b48-4e1a-bfcc-01ff3c8cf754") {
    id
    ...F1
  }
}

fragment F1 on Video {
  url
  name
}
```

becomes this:

```
fromGlobalId { type: '', id: '\u000e6]_v{vxsn\u001eU/\u001b}G>SW_]O\u001c>x' }
```

However, if I do

[image]

I get

```
globalId  U3RvcmU6
fromGlobalId { type: 'Store', id: '' }
```

Comment: can you include `dataToConnection`?

Comment: `storeType` is a `GraphQLObjectType` and you passed interfaces to the constructor. I'm not sure if there is an assessor like that.

Comment: @brysgo my connection (allVideosConnection) and also (video) node is of the same type (they have to be). How else can I do it ?

Comment: I was simply responding to your question about logging the interface.

Comment: @brysgo if you look at this example here: https://github.com/taion/relay-todomvc/blob/master/src/data/schema.js#L69 they are clearly passing interfaces to `GraphQLObjectType `

Comment: First of all, it looks like your `video` field should not return a `connectionType`. Can you describe simply what is the schema you want to achieve ? Only which fields you want and what you want to return, I think you confused a lot of parts together and I could help there.

Comment: @whitep4nther `video` should return a node while right now it returns either null or object with properties whose values are null. All I want really is to be able to get one video (by passing in that video id) and get many videos (queries of which are displayed in the question). This is the schema I want to achieve : https://api.graph.cool/relay/v1/ciy4izudz00320148u9ycnvqe?query=query%20%7B%0A%20%20viewer%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20Pokemon(id%3A%20%22ciy4izxpk12kj0177nz9ce22j%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20name%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20url%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D&variables=

Comment: I have a suspicion: the videos you return from the DB need to be an `instanceof Video`, but I don't see that they are (i.e. via using `Object.assign` with a class `Video`). The second function in the `nodeDefinitions` requires this so that objects can be resolved to their GraphQL types. In my implementation, I used `Object.assign` on objects I retrieved from the database to make them the proper types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to make node definitions work, all I had to do was this:

```
class Video {}
let video = new Video()
return Object.assign(video, data.Items[0])
```

i.e. create class with the same name as type name
and then Object.assign to it

Just doing this, doesn't work:

```
return {Video: data.Items[0]}
```

I also need to create IDs in the database like that: `Video:f4623d92-3b48-4e1a-bfcc-01ff3c8cf754`, where I am essentially putting `type` and randomly generated unique id together separated by a colon (`:`) and then encode it with `toGlobalId` function of `graphql-relay-js` library (so I end up with `VmlkZW86ZjQ2MjNkOTItM2I0OC00ZTFhLWJmY2MtMDFmZjNjOGNmNzU0Og==`), so then I can decode it with `fromGlobalId` so that `node definitions` can retrieve both `type` and `id`(`{ type: 'Video', id: 'f4623d92-3b48-4e1a-bfcc-01ff3c8cf754:' }`), after which I still need to add `fromGlobalId(globalId).id.replace(/\:$/, ''))` to remove the trailing colon (`:`).
`

Also, `interfaces` are not meant to be accessible, they are just for configuration.